# How to use analytic functions to find the next-most-recent timestamp in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, window-functions

I am currently using a self-join to calculate the next-most-recent timestamp for any given row:

```
SELECT t.COLUMN1,
       t.SOME_OTHER_COLUMN,
       t.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN,
       MAX(pt.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN) AS PREV_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN
FROM Table1 t
LEFT JOIN Table1 pt ON pt.COLUMN1 = t.COLUMN1
                   AND pt.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN < t.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN
                   AND pt.SOME_OTHER_COLUMN = SOME_LITERAL_VALUE
GROUP BY t.COLUMN1,
         t.SOME_OTHER_COLUMN,
         t.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN
```

The problem is, I need to do this multiple times, for multiple comparisons, which will require multiple nested self-joins, which will be very ugly code, and probably very slow to execute.

How do you accomplish this same thing, but using analytic functions instead?
I started writing some code, but it looks wrong:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.COLUMN1,
                t.SOME_OTHER_COLUMN,
                t.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN,

                MAX(CASE WHEN t.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN < t.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN
                          AND t.SOME_OTHER_COLUMN = SOME_LITERAL_VALUE
                         THEN t.TIMESTAMP END) OVER
                    (PARTITION BY t.COLUMN1) AS PREV_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN1,

                MAX(CASE WHEN t.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN < t.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN
                          AND t.SOME_OTHER_COLUMN = SOME_OTHER_LITERAL_VALUE
                         THEN t.TIMESTAMP END) OVER
                    (PARTITION BY t.COLUMN1) AS PREV_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN2

FROM Table1 t
```

As soon as I saw `WHEN t.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN < t.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN` I thought *"This can't be right ..."*

I know there are many other ways of using analytic functions, such as `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, but I'm new to analytic functions, and I don't know how to implement those.

What's the best way to use analytic functions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could do a conditional window max with a frame specification, as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COLUMN1,
    SOME_OTHER_COLUMN,
    TIMESTAMP_COLUMN,
    MAX(CASE WHEN SOME_OTHER_COLUMN = 'SOME_LITERAL_VALUE' THEN TIMESTAMP_COLUMN END) 
        OVER(
            PARTITION BY COLUMN1 
            ORDER BY TIMESTAMP_COLUMN
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
        ) PREV_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN
FROM Table1 t
```

This will get you the greatest timestamp within previous records having the same `COLUMN1`, and whose `SOME_OTHER_COLUMN` is equal to the desired litteral value.